# ask for suggestions how fields to add to my message class

Tags: java, io, message, messenger

I'm building an IM program using java IO, and I have an Object called Message.
what field do you recommend me to add to Message Class?
I did the folowing:

```
 public class Message implements Serializable {

    static private final long serialVersionUID=12525452;

    enum commands{
    LEAVE, 
    ONLINELISTREQUEST,
    SENT,
    DELIVERED,
    READ; 
    }

    enum types{
    TEXT,
    VEDIO,
    PICTURE,
    AUDIO,
    COMMAND,
    //...... what to add?? 
    }

    // fields..
    private   String From;
    private   String To;
    private   String Body;
    private   int type; 
    private   String url;
    private   int command; 
    //what to add??
```

Comment: Are you asking us what you want your program to do?

Comment: Not exactly,  I told it's IM messenger, so there are known concepts of what field the message contain, so I ask if you have idea  what regular message field,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALso have variable as STATE which will be having values as:-

SEEN, SENT, etc..

This will help in tracking of message and also launch a threads which will keep on checking whether messages which don't have status as SENT/ RECEIVED just resend them

Comment: thx Tushar, is it recommended to add list of online users(big list) with the message!!

Comment: No from coding perspective there is no need to add senders list to message as message is having sender field in it and there is no correlation between online users and message as message is not going to be sent to all online users even if its is sent in a case then there is no need to add that field in class.

Please voteup/mark as answer if u like the post

Answer (score 0):

Just use the teachings of Object Oriented concepts. A class should have attributes that are really properties of the entity represented by that class.